# javascript .map(x => x && y); why result y

Tags: javascript

This code is result why [5,5,5,5] ? 
 "&&" what is doing in code ? 
 Could you light me up

```js
var array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16]; 
const map1 = array1.map(x => x && 5);
console.log(map1);
```

Comment: "x && 5" returns 5 if x is defined/truthy and else x. It is like "x ? 5 : x".

Comment: `Logical and` is first evaluating the `x` variable which is coming to be `true` and evaluating the constant `5`, which again is true and returning the `5`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: If `x` evaluate to **truthy** than `x && 5` returns 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, if `x` is truthy, then `x && y` will return `y`.

Your array contains numeric values that are all truthy. If one of your values was `falsy`, like `0` then `x && y` would return `x` instead - give it a try!

Learn more on MDN...

- [About truthy (links to falsey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
- [About the logical shortcut operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: A simple sandbox to see this in action: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input

Answer (score 0):

`x => x && 5` basically behaves the same as:

```js
x => {
  if (x) {
    return 5;
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}
```